# tinymce create comment function does not read updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I have implemented an editor with tinymce package and I have the comments plug in. In addition I have built a functionality as follows: When a user select a text, I store it on a state variable in order to read it from the tiny's built in create function and send all the data to my backend. Overall I want when a user select a text in order to create a comment, to send the highlighted text to my backend through the tiny's create function but the create function only reads the initial state of the variable and does not read the updated value. The code id as below:

```
import { Editor as EditorMce } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
//... some imports

function Editor() {
let [highlightedText, setHighlightedText] = useState("");

  const tinycomments_create = (req, done, fail) => {
    const { content, createdAt } = req;

    console.log("highligt inside create function");
    console.log(highlightedText); //This is always an empy string, the initial value
//and does not update when user highlights a text

    fetch("my-backend-endpoint", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        content,
        createdAt,
        highlightedText,
      }),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to create comment");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((req2) => {
        const conversationUid = req2.id;
        done({ conversationUid });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        fail(e);
      });
  };

//... some existing code and I return the component

<EditorMce
                value={session ? session.sessionText : ""}
                onEditorChange={handleOnEditorChange}
                init={{
                  init_instance_callback: (editor) => {
                    editor.on("MouseUp", function (e) {
                      if (e.view.getSelection().toString() !== "") {
                        setHighlightedText(e.view.getSelection().toString());
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  content_css: "writer",
                  height: "80%",
                  width: "95%",
                  plugins: [
                    "tinycomments",
                    "advlist",
                    "autolink",
                    "lists",
                    "link",
                    "image",
                    "charmap",
                    "preview",
                    "anchor",
                    "searchreplace",
                    "visualblocks",
                    "code",
                    "fullscreen",
                    "insertdatetime",
                    "media",
                    "table",
                    "code",
                    "help",
                    "wordcount",
                  ],
                  menubar: "file edit view insert format tools tc",
                  menu: {
                    tc: {
                      title: "Comments",
                      items: "addcomment showcomments deleteallconversations",
                    },
                  },
                  toolbar:
                    "undo redo | fontsizeinput fontfamily | blocks | " +
                    "bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
                    "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
                    "removeformat | addcomment showcomments | help",
                  content_style:
                    "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px }" +
                    ".tox-comments-visible span.tox-comment  { background-color: #90EE90!important; }.tox-comments-visible span.tox-comment--active { background-color: black; }",
                  tinycomments_create,
                  tinycomments_reply,
                  tinycomments_edit_comment,
                  tinycomments_delete,
                  tinycomments_delete_all,
                  tinycomments_delete_comment,
                  tinycomments_lookup,
                }}
              />
}
```

How can I update the value of highlightedText inside tinycomments_create. I have tried the useCallback hook with no result. Also I have tried to add the tinycomments_create inside a useEffect and set it every time the highlightedText updates but again with no results.
Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `useState`, you can use a `useRef`:

```js
// replace
const [highlightedText, setHighlightedText] = useState("");

// by
const highlightedText = useRef("");
```

Then when updating this value

```js
// replace
 setHighlightedText(e.view.getSelection().toString());

// by
highlightedText.current = e.view.getSelection().toString();
```

Finally, inside the `tinycomments_create` function, you can read the most up-to-date value from `highlightedText.current`.

Note that updating a ref won't cause a render, thus the UI won't get updated. If you want the UI to update, you would have to use a `useState` along with the proposed `useRef` approach.

TLDR: using `useRef` is essential for the `tinycomments_create` to read the last value of `highlightedText`; while using `useState` is essential if you want to make a render and update the UI.

Comment: Can you further explain why useRef works and not useState? As you imagine I am very new to react world. Thanks in advance

Comment: let me start by clarifying that useState might be enough in many situations, i believe here we needed the useRef because of the way EditorMce works under the hood. I assume that EditorMce takes the props and never updates them later, so even when the tinycomments_create got updated (aka tinycomments_create now sees the new state value), the EditorMce will not see this new tinycomments_create function, and thus it will keep calling the old tinycomments_create function that has the initial empty state.

Comment: while if tinycomments_create uses a ref, it will always get access to the last update to date value, it's how ref works (and in general, it's how referencial equality works in javascript)

Comment: so when using ref, EditorMce will keep seeing the initial tinycomments_create all the time, however, this tinycomments_create can see the up to date ref, which was not the case when tinycomments_create uses a state.

Comment: you can look into "closures in javascript" ... maybe something like this too showing how closures work with react https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/